# can we use different schema's view in my local schema procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, view

Lets take my current schema name is **sch1**. if i have a view as **v1** in different schema named as **sch2.** so i want to use that view (**sch2.v1**) in my current schema(sch1)'s **procedure**.

is it possible ?. is yes please give one example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, by granting select privilege to sch1 for sch2.v1 :

```
SQL> conn sch2/pwd1
SQL> grant select on v1 to sch1 [ with grant option ];
SQL> conn sch1/pwd2
SQL> select * from sch2.v1;  -- assuming you query sch2.v1 inside your procedure
```